# Wrong Query to save data into Mysql using NODEJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I try to Update the data into mysql by using node.js . I am getting the problem when I try to assign the value from the droplist into variable search and update. It comes from json. It works when I use this query:

```
con.query("UPDATE `Good` SET name = ? WHERE name = ?",[dataupdating,datasearching],function(err,result){
```

What should i need to fix when i not only SET namm and Where name. Ex : SET phone Where name. i am try to using this code to update

```
var search = req.body.search;
var update = req.body.update;
con.query("UPDATE `Good` SET update = ? WHERE search = ?",[dataupdating,datasearching],function(err,result){
```

Thank for helping

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While using column name from request body is generally bad, you should be able to use NodeJS string formatting using backtick:

```
`UPDATE \`Good\` SET ${update} = ? WHERE ${search} = ?`
```

Remember to escape update and search otherwise you will encounter SQL injection.

Comment: the update and search here are the field of database. If the update = phone, search = name. i hope it will update the phone of people who has name = datasearching.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comment. I understand what you are trying to achieve now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I updated my table using node js and MySQL.
I created a database practise and table named users

```
use practise;
create table users
    (id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(200) not null,
    phone int not null,
    address varchar(255) not null,
    unique(phone));
    
insert into users values
    (default, "Abhishek Kumar", 77232411, "abcsd34, sds"),
    (default, "Rock", 78832324, "abcserd, sds"),
    (default, "Xavi", 77234324, "abcsd, s23ds");
```

Then I simply used this node js server side code to update the address of the user using the phone number:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Connect to database

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'practise',
  multipleStatements: true,
});
mysqlConnection.connect((error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(`Database connected!`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Failed to connect to database!`);
  }
});

app.put('/update-address', (req, res) => {
  let body = req.body;
  let newAddress = body.address;
  let phone = body.phone;
  query = 'update users set address = ? where phone = ?';
  mysqlConnection.query(query, [newAddress, phone], (err, response) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.status(200).send(response);
    } else {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`Listening on port 5000... `));
```

Then simply create a put request in postman with this json body:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Abhishek Kumar",
    "phone": 77232411,
    "address": "Street - 2, behind the movie theatre"
}
```

This is how I updated the record.

Comment: thanks mate. I know my question is not clearly. In your code, you want to change the address with the condition is phone. However in my project , the field to set and the condition is unstable. it change base on the select of users. So i have the search and update value. I get from user input. But when i using this value from search and update variable, it give me the wrong query

Comment: Yup, I just wanted you to show how the update works. You could refer this and make changes in your code. Mark the answer as correct if you find it helpful.